# How to change the opacity from a jlabel?

Tags: jlabel, opacity

To explain it better, i want to to change the opacity of a jlabel that contains an image like a %20, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was investigating and finally i did it , Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String format = "png";

    //We create the image to draw on it.

    Image img= new ImageIcon("Source").getImage();
    BufferedImage bi= new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // We drawing

    Graphics2D g2D = bi.createGraphics();
    AlphaComposite ac= AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,  0.2f);
            g2D.setComposite(ac);
            g2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null),null);
            g2D.dispose();
    // Write the image in the file .
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, format, new File("Source"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Write Error");

            }
}
```